# Выборка по трём таблицам (товары связанные с магазином)

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица `PRODUCT`

```
PRODUCT_ID  NAME
01          Товар 1
02          Товар 2
03          Товар 3
```

Есть таблица `SHOPS`

```
SHOPS_ID    NAME
01          Магазин 1
02          Магазин 2
03          Магазин 3
```

Есть таблица, которая их связывает `PRODUCT_TO_SHOPS`

```
PRODUCT_ID  SHOPS_ID
01          01
01          02
02          03
03          01
03          02
03          03
```

Товары могут относится сразу к нескольким магазинам.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать запрос, чтобы получить товары, которые относятся только к заданным/заданному магазину.

Например:

1) SHOPS_ID = 03, выдало Товар 2, Товар 3

2) SHOPS_ID = 01 и 02 выдало Товар 1, Товар 3

Comment: Может вам почитать основы sql или что-то такое?

Answer (score 0):

У вас что-то все капслоком, нечитаемо, но как бы там ни было:

```
SELECT PRODUCT.NAME
FROM PRODUCT_TO_SHOPS
JOIN SHOPS ON SHOPS.SHOPS_ID = PRODUCT_TO_SHOPS.SHOPS_ID
JOIN PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT_TO_SHOPS.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE PRODUCT_TO_SHOPS.SHOPS_ID IN (ид_магазинов_через_запятую)
GROUP BY PRODUCT_TO_SHOPS.PRODUCT_ID
```

Правда, тут можно обойтись без `JOIN SHOPS`, но если нужны будут данные из все таблиц, то так.